# How to create a Database Replica in AWS RDS using RDS instance, created using DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I want to create a DB Read Replica using aws CDK. I am creating a RDS DatabaseInstance using method DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot in aws CDK. I want to use this RDS instance to create a Read Replica using DatabaseInstanceReadReplica method. DatabaseInstanceReadReplica takes a sourceDatabaseInstance as a parameter. For sourceDatabaseInstance I am passing the DatabaseInstance returned from DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot method. But I get the following error:

> Type 'DatabaseInstanceReadReplica' is missing the following properties from type 'DatabaseInstance': sourceCfnProps, singleUserRotationApplication, multiUserRotationApplication, addRotationSingleUser, addRotationMultiUsers(2739)

How do I fix this issue? Any help is appreciated. Below is the code.

```
    mySqlRdsInstance: DatabaseInstance
    mySqlRdsReplicaInstance: DatabaseInstance
this.mySqlRdsInstance = new DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot(this, props.rdsParameters.instanceName, {
            instanceIdentifier: props.rdsParameters.instanceIdentifier,
            snapshotIdentifier: props.rdsParameters.snapshotIdentifier || '',
            engine: DatabaseInstanceEngine.MYSQL,
            vpc: props.vpc,
            vpcSubnets: {
                subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
            },
          })
        
        this.mySqlRdsReplicaInstance = new DatabaseInstanceReadReplica(this, "", {
            sourceDatabaseInstance: this.mySqlRdsInstance,
            instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.LARGE),
            vpc: props.vpc,
            vpcSubnets: {
                subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
            },
        })
```

Comment: You've declared your `mySqlRdsInstance` instance to be of type `DatabaseInstance`, but you're initializing it as `DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot`, which is a different type. Perhaps you want to declare them as `IDatabaseInstance` if for some reason you want to keep them abstract.